# How do I compile an out-of-tree kernel driver on Fedora to fix super-slow wifi?

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers

I have a HP laptop with Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter. The laptop came with Windows 8.1 and the wifi worked just fine, but since I wanted to try Linux, I installed Ubuntu, and the wifi worked super slow, and it was unstable, so then I thought that installing Fedora might fix the problem, but it didn't.

So I started reading everywhere in forums and I found out that this solution has helped a few people: (I'm on Fedora now btw)

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

but whenever I type the 'make' command I get the following result:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64/build M=/home/Betim/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:53: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

can somebody please help me, because I really like Fedora, and I want to stick to it, I would hate to go back to Windows...

Comment: you dont have kernel header files. `sudo yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just did that, and I still get the same message..

Comment: How does your `/lib/modules/3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64/build` look like? And how does your `/usr/src/` look like?

Comment: Make sure you're running the kernel version that you installed the devel package for. That command will install the newest version by default, and that might not match what you are running, and it appears the build process picks up the version info from the running kernel.

Comment: @Miline Sorry, I am such a noob, thanks for hanging with me. For the first command I got: 
bash: /lib/modules/3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64/build: No such file or directory
and for the second :
bash: /usr/src/: Is a directory

Comment: @mattdm yeah mate I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: Type `uname -a` and see if the version matches. If not, a reboot should fix that.

Comment: Do `ls /usr/src/` and show that

Comment: @mattdm I got 3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 27 19:09:10 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
and I will reboot now :)

Comment: @Miline hi it shows something in blue debug and kernels ...

Comment: do `ls /usr/src/kernel`. Basically we are trying to find out where your kernel headers are installed.

Comment: @Miline ok I got: 3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64  3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64+debug

Comment: Ok, cool, so rebooting should take you from that older 3.17.4 kernel to the 3.19 one.

Comment: And the good news is: _this alone may fix your root problem_, because from the git repo you linked, it appears that the plan was to merge the fixes into the 3.18 kernel.

Comment: Sorry.. no google...Yeah just need to boot into that kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the core problem there is that it's looking for the kernel header files needed to compile new kernel modules. You can install those with

sudo yum install kernel-devel

But the further trick is that the compile process is looking for kernel devel files *which match your running kernel*. You can run `uname -r` to find the currently-running kernel, and `rpm -q kernel-devel`. By default on an updated system, you will probably have multiple kernel versions installed, because the update system saves the last two for safety. But, unless you've rebooted after the last update, you may not be running the latest one. By contrast, the kernel-devel package is usually kept to the latest (and that's what you'll get with the yum install command above).

So, if you reboot, you should have the newer kernel both installed and running, and when you run `make`, you'll see it looking for the newer version instead of 3.17.4.

That said, there is a [note on the github repo you've linked](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/4#issuecomment-56222584) which says that fixes for slow speed were slated to go into the 3.18 kernel, and since we're at 3.19.3 now, it is very likely that simply updating alone will fix your issue.

(Disclaimer: I work on Fedora for my job, so I'm not unbiased, but I do want to add that our awesome kernel team does a great job of tracking the latest upstream kernel very closely and quickly, and rolls those updates out across all of our currently-supported releases, making Fedora a great choice for hardware-enablement issues like this.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, and your time. I think that it is pretty cool that you work for Fedora, because I really fell in love with the system. Because I hate to be a pain in the ass, and waste peoples time, I think that I am just going to switch back to windows, because eventhough I did everything that I was supposed to do, I still get the same message. Sorry that I cannot upvote your post, because I have a below 15 reputation, it seems like it is not possible to do it....

Comment: @BetimNeutron Is your speed better with the newer kernel?

Comment: Asking for help isn't annoying, by the way. We all have to start somewhere!

Comment: thanks... I can't really tell since it is inconsistent, it may be fine now, but a minute later note. This is the current result :http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/4257669044 is it okay that the upload speed is that much higher? And what bothers me so much is that eventhough I have the newest kernel, that 'make' still goes and looks for the older one 3.17...go figure

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem was you do not have kernel headers installed. If you do `sudo yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers` and boot into the new installed kernel. Then your driver `make` will be able to find your kernel headers in `/lib/modules/{uname -r}/build`

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help. I still get the same error message though, anyway I don't want to be annoying or anything, I think that I am just going to switch back to Windows...

Comment: Ohh and btw, I cannot upvote your post either, because it seems like that is impossible to do if you have a reputation below 15 (and I do since I am new here)..